# sum or count values/string based on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, merge, count

I want to count the number of rows based on multiple columns. Suppose I want to show the number in below df where **AgeGroup == "36-45 AgeGroup"** and **SocioEcnomicStatus =="2"**. This should **count as "2"** as per example of below dataframe. I tired below query with **sum** and **addmargins** function.

```
sum(filter(df$AgeGroup=="36-45 AgeGroup" & df$SocioEcnomicStatus =="2"))
```

This says `no applicable method for filter applied to an object of class "logical"`. I am not sure how it should be done by not changing the datatype. Or if it needs to change the data type then what should be the query or function in R.

Thanks

| S.NO | SocioEcnomicStatus | Age | AgeGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 2 | 43 | 36-45 AgeGroup |
| P2 | 5 | 27 | 26-35 AgeGroup |
| P3 | 1 | 34 | 26-35 AgeGroup |
| P4 | 2 | 43 | 36-45 AgeGroup |
| P5 | 3 | 78 | 76-85 AgeGroup |
| P6 | 4 | 89 | 86+ AgeGroup |

Comment: `filter {stats} Applies linear filtering to a univariate time series or to each series separately of a multivariate time series.`

Comment: `subset(df,AgeGroup=="36-45" & SocioEcnomicStatus=="2")`?

Comment: In base R use nrow(subset( ... )) as in above comment

Comment: @user2974951 It does return me the total number of rows but with all the variables in a or in a datafrae. I want to get a single value in terms of count like "2" as I mentioned in the example above in my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filter {stats}  Applies linear filtering to a univariate time series or to each series separately of a multivariate time series.

Use

```
nrow(subset(df,AgeGroup=="36-45 AgeGroup" & SocioEcnomicStatus=="2"))
```